# Minimalistic IIS site not accessible externally

Tags: iis

1. Made a minimalistic Hello World site.
2. Could access the site from outside when using IIS Express.
3. Switched to IIS version 10.0.19041.444 on the same Windows 10 box.
4. Behind the router (from inside), I get Hello World from: http://localhost:33333
5. Can ping the IP from outside.
6. All ports are forwarded to the webserver (by using DMZ in the router).
7. The firewall is turned off.
8. Applications Pool: DefaultAppPool
9. Cannot find any new entries in the logs after trying to connect.
10. <s>The port was added using: netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:33333/ user=everyone</s>
11. Bindings: Type:HTTP, HostName: , Port:33333, IP:*
12. Did iisreset.
13. http://82.65.140.190:33333 : Chrome: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: About 4, find another machine in the same internal network and access your IIS machine please. That result is critical before moving on to the next steps. About 10 that's unnecessary because IIS sites do not need any reserved URL. Delete that please. About 6, what is "all ports are forwarded to the webserver"?

Comment: @LexLi will do what you suggested in about 1 hour. Thanks!

Comment: @LexLi I cannot access the site from another machine inside!!! Can ping it though. Great progress! Removed the netsh entry from 10 as you said. 6 means that I added the machine's MAC address to DMZ.

Comment: @LexLi when I try to TELNET to the webserver from inside, I get: Unable to open a connection to the host on port 33333. Also, the message in the browser (internal and external) changed to: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: I think so far you have done all necessary setttings on that IIS machine (1. set a good binding; 2. Windows Firewall is turned off on this box; 3. `http://localhost:33333` is accessible on this box.). The internal access failure can be quite complex, as you seem to configure your router partially. Not sure what's the necessary steps for your router, so you need to check its manual or contact its vendor. Stack Overflow does not cover that.

Comment: @LexLi But since the problem is on the local network as well, I guess the problem cannot be the router. Also, the same setup on the router worked perfectly on IIS Express.

Comment: @Yster set the router to access the ip address. set the allow port number or try to use the port 80. check the iis site binding detail. restart the router

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Thanks for the comment. The problem is not the router. I am trying to access the site from another computer on the same LAN. I can ping the host. But cannot telnet the port. I guess the problem is either with some IIS settings or bindings....or there is an access rights problem on windows or IIS. What should the bindings look like to access the site from another computer locally? Is this correct? (1): Type:HTTP, HostName: , Port:80, IP:* (2): Type:HTTP, HostName: , Port:80, IP:192.168.1.66